# How to preserve type hints despite variable type annotation during assignment

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance, pyright

I am writing a `Lazy` class that works like `partial`, but has some extra functionalities.
The goal is to pre-initialize an object by wrapping it in the `Lazy` class and later finish the initialization by calling `to_eager`, where the user can provide some additional arguments. The issue is with preserving type hints in IDE.

Here is the code

```
from typing import Callable, Generic, ParamSpec, Type, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


class Lazy(Generic[T, P]):  # Any makes it ok to asign to any other type

    def __init__(
        self, cls: Type[T] | Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs
    ):
        self.cls = cls
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def to_eager(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        assert not args
        kwg = {**self.kwargs, **kwargs}
        return self.cls(*self.args, **kwg)


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, y: int = 1):
        self.y = y


l = Lazy(SomeClass, y=5)
l.to_eager()  # here VSCode hints me with (y: int -> 1)
```

When I try to call `to_eager()`, I get a nice hint about possible args for the original class.

[image]

Now the issue is, if this is combined with variable type assignment

```
l: Lazy = Lazy(SomeClass, y=5)
l.to_eager()  # type hint is gone, I get (... -> Unknown)
```

This can be improved a bit by

```
l: Lazy[SomeClass, ...] = Lazy(SomeClass, y=5)
l.to_eager()  # I get (... -> SomeClass)
```

but this does not contain the args.

My question is - how to preserve the args type hints in this case while also doing the variable type assignment? The type assignment is needed eg when I combine this with a dataclass. Maybe there is some configuration for `pyright` to not do type widening? Or perhaps vscode has some useful option for this?

What I tried so far:

1. Pass `P` as the second argument in `Lazy[SomeClass, P]`, but getting warning that P has no meaning in this context and also no type hints from VSCode

Comment: Take a look at this github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/discussions/5597

Comment: You can't do this without duplicating the signature (e.g. in a callback protocol). I suggest not using type annotations to infer dataclass fields, but just directly use `dataclasses.field(default=Lazy(SomeClass, y=5))`.

Comment: Thanks. Good idea. Out of curiosity, how would the callback protocol look like?

Answer (score 1):

`Lazy` by itself is equivalent to `Lazy[Any, Any]`, overriding the inferred type of `Lazy[SomeClass, int]`. It's the laziness (pun intended) of not specifying a precise type hint that prevents the editor from providing an argument hint.

`...` itself is recognized as shorthand for `types.EllipsisType`.

---

What you would *want* is for the editor to support some notion of type-variable binding so that you can write one "type" whose value is bound by the actual argument passed to `Lazy`, something like

```
l: Lazy[Cls, T] = Lazy(SomeClass, y=5)
```

and have `Cls` and `T` bound (perhaps just for this assignment) to `SomeClass` and `int`, respectively.

Comment: And is there a way how to do the binding you describe? I am aware of the `ParamSpec` option but that does not seem to work as you suggest. What I do not understand about this is that the information is readily available, but the ide decides to select the less specific variant, even though the more specific one is more correct and provides more information.

Comment: No, everything below the line is hypothetical at best. I think the main point is that if you are going to provide an annotation, you need to provide the full annotation. The IDE assumes that if you provide `Lazy` explicitly, you meant to provide the less-specific annotation, not that you wanted "the rest" of the type inferred.

Comment: Got it. It could  be useful to be able to specify if I want to do the type widening or not in some config.